# How do I rename X-axis tick marks inside individual facet_wraps() with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, bioinformatics

I am trying to plot data with facet_wraps, but when i add scale_x_discrete labels, they repeat inside each individual facet.

Here is my code:

```r
phy_gre_5S_c0_samp = mean_data_type %>%
  filter(country == "Greece") %>% 
  filter(WP == "5S") %>% 
  filter(phase == "C0") %>% 
#  filter(Taxonomy != "Unclassified") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sample_pretty_type,
             y = mean_relab,
             fill = Taxonomy)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(c("Fertilized eggs","Yolk sack\nlarvae"), c("Inlet water\nto tank/farm","Tank water","Waste water"), c("Distal intestine\ntissue","Mid intestine tissue","Pyloric anterior\nintestine tissue","Intestinal tissue"),c("Feed/diet"),c("Mid intestine\ndigesta","Posterior intestine\ndigesta", "Pyloric anterior\nintestine digesta","Digesta"),c("Gills","Skin","Filet"))) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = "Relative Abundance (%)",
       x = "Sample type") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1),
        legend.key.size = unit(2, 'cm'),
        legend.position = "right") +
  facet_wrap(vars(sample_category), scales = "free") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 40))
```

And as you can see the x-axis labels i provide via scale_x_discrete repeat inside each facet like this:

[image: see image in link]

How do i avoid this?

The aim is to add linebreaks to my x-axis tick labels since they are quite long - if there is another better way to do this, perhaps that could be an alternative solution.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have a look at the [`ggh4x`](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#position-scales) package to individually set the scales (inclduing the labels, breaks, ...) per facet.

Comment: It would make sense to have a column correctly specifying what the variable is in each case before passing to the `ggplot` function. You could transform `sample_pretty_type` into the verbose labels before passing to the x-axis perhaps? Do post some sample data if it would be helpful to see this in action.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got when I commented out `scale_x_discrete` and transformed the `sample_category` column values as factors to preserve the order as seen in your figure (I assigned random values for the relative abundances):

[image: Facet-wrapped abundances by sample type and category]

Here's the code:

```
phy_gre_5S_c0_samp = mean_data_type %>%
  filter(country == "Greece") %>% 
  filter(WP == "5S") %>% 
  filter(phase == "C0")
#  filter(Taxonomy != "Unclassified") %>% 
g <- ggplot(data = transform(phy_gre_5S_c0_samp, sample_category=factor(sample_category,levels=c("Early life stages","Environmental samples","Intestinal tissues","Diet","Digesta","Other tissues"))), 
            aes(x = sample_pretty_type,
             y = mean_relab,
             fill = Taxonomy)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none") +
  # scale_x_discrete(labels = c(c("Fertilized eggs","Yolk sack\nlarvae"), c("Inlet water\nto tank/farm","Tank water","Waste water"), c("Distal intestine\ntissue","Mid intestine tissue","Pyloric anterior\nintestine tissue","Intestinal tissue"),c("Feed/diet"),c("Mid intestine\ndigesta","Posterior intestine\ndigesta", "Pyloric anterior\nintestine digesta","Digesta"),c("Gills","Skin","Filet"))) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = "Relative Abundance (%)",
       x = "Sample type") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1),
        legend.key.size = unit(2, 'cm'),
        legend.position = "right") +
  facet_wrap(vars(sample_category), scales = "free") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 40))

show(g)
```